# Как включить кнопки переключалки в слайдере?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Есть [следующий слайдер](http://wordimpress.com/demos/jflow/). Кроме стрелок вправо/влево в правом верхнем углу есть точки для переключения слайдов. Почему-то в скачанном слайдере кнопки эти отсутствуют, хотя в коде прописаны. Как можно включить эти кнопки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собрал рабочий пример: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/FHnXz/)

В этом слайдере точки для переключения слайдов нужно прописывать самому.
В приведенном примере за это отвечает вот этот html-код:

```
<div id="myController"> 
    <span class="jFlowControl"></span> 
    <span class="jFlowControl"></span> 
    <span class="jFlowControl"></span> 
    <span class="jFlowControl"></span> 
</div>
```

А вот так он подключается в настройках слайдера:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myController").jFlow({
            controller: ".jFlowControl" // указывать класс вместе с точкой!
    });
});
</script>
```

Здесь мы связываем элементы внутри **`<div>`** с id **`jFlowControl`**
с соответствующим им картинкам (по порядковому номеру).
В демо-примере 4 картинки, поэтому выводим 4 **`span`** с id **`jFlowControl`** на страницу.

Comment: Строка 443 в моем примере на **jsFiddle**. effect: "flow" - может применять два значения: "rewind" и "flow". Других настроек, увы, я не нашел. "flow", насколько я заметил, как раз не использует "перемотку".

Comment: А у меня почему-то использует и флоу, и ривайнд.

Comment: А, нет. Вы правы. Перемотки нет. Спасибо.

Comment: А можно Ваш приме как-то разом скачать?

Comment: Можно. Вот здесь: (http://rghost.ru/47372782).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.